# How can I increase the file system root using free space in my disk?

Tags: dual-boot, files, gparted, root, system

I am using ubuntu for almost a year with dual boot. Actually, I almost never use windows for a long time and I want to increase my file system root disk.
I create a free 60 gb disk space, but I cannot use it to increase file system root. The unallocated space doesn't appear. I haven't found the solution. What should I do at this point?

[image: image1]

[image: image2]

Comment: You've provided no picture, no release details or much at all..   Is the free space *contiguous* with the partition you want to expand (ie. it must be next to the partition you wish to expand, not elsewhere on the disk, which may require moving partitions around to solve)

Comment: Hey, it just worked. I had actually read that solution, but I noticed that I skipped the part about booting from the livecd. Thank you!